# java: use 3d array from method in main method

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a method which is filling two of the three dimensions of an array.

```
public static String[][] Method(){
    double[][][] chromosom = new double [50][8][4];
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){

        // generate random value ...

        chromosom[0][j][0] = value*2;
        chromosom[0][j][1] = value*3;
        chromosom[0][j][2] = value*5;
        chromosom[0][j][3] = value*9;
    }
}
```

Now I want to use this array in my main to generate 50 of these arrays and to save them all in one array.

```
static double[][][] chromosom = new double [50][8][4];

public static void main(String[] args){
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        Method();
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            chromosom[i][j][0];
            chromosom[i][j][1];
            chromosom[i][j][2];
            chromosom[i][j][3];
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I am not able to reach the chromosom array with its values from my main method.

Comment: It seems you are trying to very weirdly use the main method. You should probably avoid that.

Comment: What you want is to `return` a value. I would suggest doing some tutorials before jumping into your own project. thenewboston has a really good video tutorial series.

Comment: 'static double[][][] = new double [50][8][4];'.. where is the variable here?

Comment: @CKing forgot it, its in now.

Comment: You're creating a *local* variable in your method. That has nothing to do with the *field* you're reading from in `main`. Also, you appear to be trying to use array access as a whole statement... please provide a [mcve] rather than pseudo-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile. Your Method should return a String[][]. Why create the 3-dimension double array if this method should only create a 2-dimension String array?
How about this:

```
public static double[][] generateXY(){
    double[][] result = new double[8][4];
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){

        // generate random value ...

        result[j][0] = value*2;
        result[j][1] = value*3;
        result[j][2] = value*5;
        result[j][3] = value*9;
    }
    return result;
}
```

And then in your main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    double[][][] xyz = new double[50][8][4];
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        xyz[i] = generateXY();
    }
}
```

Methods and variables should be renamed, I don't know what exaclty you're doing with it.